# Java8 remove keys from List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, java-stream, filtering

I have a List<Map<String, Object>> and I need to remove the nested key = "age" if exists and return the List of map. How can I do this elegantly with streams()?

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("Name", "Michael");
map1.put("Age", 43);
map1.put("City", "Paris");

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map2.put("Name", "Tanja");
map2.put("Age", 23);
map2.put("City", "Berlin");

Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map3.put("Name", "Diego");
map3.put("Age", 35);
map3.put("City", "Madrid");

List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
list.add(map3);
```

Example:

```
[
     {Name="Michael", age=43, city="Paris"},
     {Name="Tanja", age=23, city="Berlin"},
     {Name="Diego", age=35, city="Madrid"}
]
```

to:

```
[
     {Name="Michael", city="Paris"},
     {Name="Tanja", city="Berlin"},
     {Name="Diego", city="Madrid"}
]
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you need copies or do you need to edit the existing strictures? (If the latter, then that problem is not too well suited to streams)

Comment: @paulsm4 OP is not trying to remove element of a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
 list.forEach(stringObjectMap -> {
     stringObjectMap.remove("Age");
 });
```

Since the map object is a reference, you can simply delete a key from the map without copying it into another map object.

Comment: A little bit smaller code: `list.forEach(stringObjectMap::remove);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.entrySet().removeIf(y -> y.getKey().equals("Age")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```